Division based recurrence with negative coefficients, e.g. $F(n)= -F(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) - F(\lfloor n/3\rfloor)$
A famous problem of Erdos dealt with the division-based recurrence $a_n = a_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}+a_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}+a_{\lfloor n/6\rfloor}$ with $a_0=1$ (and was about the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}n$, which in fact equals the memorable $\frac{12}{\log(432)}$). In the link, there is an MSE answer linking a paper of Erdos (and others) solving the same problem for general divison-based recurrences with positive coefficients, based on probability methods (renewal theory). [EDIT: another answer mentioned a solution by Noam Elkies using Dirichlet series and the residue theorem; perhaps this method is more amenable to negative coefficients --- indeed some comments below seem to be pursuing this strategy.] A paper cited in that one, also by Erdos, tackles similar problems (also divison-based recurrence with positive coefficients), with different methods.
I am wondering if division-based recurrences with negative coefficients have been studied; the simplest non-trivial example may be something like $F(n)= -F(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) - F(\lfloor n/3\rfloor)$ with $F(0)=1$, or $F(n)= F(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) - F(\lfloor n/3\rfloor)$. Basic questions include: upper/lower bounds of $F(n)$, limsup and liminf asymptotics of $F(n)$ divided against various power functions, the maximum amount $F$ jumps as $n\mapsto n+1$, etc.
If there is not much previous research, for this questions, maybe I'll restrict attention just to finding good upper and lower bounds for $F(n)$ as defined with the titular recurrence with $F(0)=1$.

This counts the numbers up to $n$ of the form $2^a 3^b$ weighted in some way, right? What's the weight?

if we look at $f(n) = F(n) - F(n-1)$, $g(n) = \begin{cases} -1 & n = 2, 3 \ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ then I believe we should have $f = f * g$ except up to some correction for small values, so I think the Dirichlet series of $f$ should be fairly simple

The Dirichlet series of $f$ is $\frac{-3}{1 + 2^{-s} + 3^{-s}}$. It shouldn't be too hard to get the sum from this via Perron's formula

This also gives $f(2^a 3^b) = -3 (-1)^{a+b} \binom{a+b}a$ (and 0 for all numbers not of this form)

@DanielWeber Why do only numbers of the form $2^a 3^b$ contribute?

@WillSawin this can be seen by writing the Dirichlet series as $-3 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-2^{-s}-3^{-s})^i$.

@DanielWeber It seems like you are ignoring the floor functions, and it is not obvious to me why this is OK. It's conceivable to me that the subtraction $F(n)-F(n-1)$ does this but it's not clear.

I am using the formula $H(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x g(n) F(\lfloor \frac x n \rfloor)$ where $h$ is the Dirichlet convolution of $f$ and $g$. Setting $g(n) =\begin{cases}1 & n=1,2,3\ 0 & 3<n\end{cases}$ it's clear this should be a $0$ for $3<x$, so we can find $h$, and then $f = h * g^{-1}$
